# query through five tables with nested Any operator

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I'm trying to create a single query to get all the users that belong to a certain announcement, but I cannot seem to get my query to work.

I'm getting the following error:

> Unable to create a constant value of type 'RequestSupplierEntity'.
>   Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this
>   context.

I do not know exactly what the error message means, or what I should do/avoid to prevent it. Any help or insight into the problem, or even a working query, would be greatly appreciated.
It seems to me that a single T-SQL query should be possible using a EXIST subquery, I just don't know if entity framework is able to construct it in this case.

My query statement:

```
Users.Where(u => notification.Announcement.RequestSuppliers.Any(rs => rs.Supplier.OrganisationId == u.OrganisationId));
```

*Users* is a DBSet. *notification* is the entity instance I'm trying to find the associated users for. I have the feeling that the problem lies with using the NotificationEntity instance within the *where* method of the DBSet, but I don't see how I should do this otherwise.

The POCO entities relate as follows:

- User has a Organisation
- Supplier is a Organisation
- RequestSupplier is a Supplier
- RequestSupplier has a Announcement
- Notification has a Announcement

So what I'm trying to do is to get the Users with OrganisationId's that belong to the Suppliers that are associated with the Announcement through the RequestSupplier.

The associated FluentAPI is:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<NotificationEntity>()
    .HasOptional<AnnouncementEntity>(n => n.Announcement)
    .WithMany(a => a.Notifications)
    .HasForeignKey(n => n.AnnouncementId)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
modelBuilder.Entity<RequestSupplierEntity>()
    .HasRequired<SupplierEntity>(rs => rs.Supplier)
    .WithMany(s => s.RequestSuppliers)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
modelBuilder.Entity<RequestSupplierEntity>()
    .HasKey(rs => new { rs.SupplierId });
modelBuilder.Entity<RequestSupplierEntity>()
    .HasRequired<AnnouncementEntity>(rs => rs.Announcement)
    .WithMany(a => a.RequestSuppliers)
    .HasForeignKey(rs => rs.AnnouncementId)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
modelBuilder.Entity<SupplierEntity>()
    .HasRequired<OrganisationEntity>(s => s.Organisation)
    .WithMany(o => o.Suppliers)
    .HasForeignKey(s => s.OrganisationId)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
modelBuilder.Entity<UserEntity>()
    .HasOptional<OrganisationEntity>(u => u.Organisation)
    .WithMany(o => o.Users)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

The notification I'm doing this query for always has an associated Announcement.

Entities:

```
[Table("Announcement")]
public class AnnouncementEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<RequestSupplierEntity> RequestSuppliers { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<NotificationEntity> Notifications { get; set; }
}

[Table("Notification")]
public class NotificationEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? AnnouncementId { get; set; }

    public virtual AnnouncementEntity Announcement { get; set; }
}

[Table("Organisation")]
public class OrganisationEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<SupplierEntity> Suppliers { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserEntity> Users { get; set; }
}

[Table("RequestSupplier")]
public class RequestSupplierEntity
{
    public int SupplierId { get; set; }
    public int AnnouncementId { get; set; }

    public virtual SupplierEntity Supplier { get; set; }
    public virtual AnnouncementEntity Announcement { get; set; }
}

[Table("Supplier")]
public class SupplierEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int OrganisationId { get; set; }

    public virtual OrganisationEntity Organisation { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<RequestSupplierEntity> RequestSuppliers { get; set; }
}

[Table("User")]
public class UserEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? OrganisationId { get; set; }

    public virtual OrganisationEntity Organisation { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure but try this

```
  db.Users.Where(u => db.Notifications.Select(n=>n.Announcement).SelectMany(a=>a.RequestSuppliers).Any(rs => rs.Supplier.OrganisationId == u.OrganisationId));
```

I guess that you try to make a collection of collections of RequestSuppliers which is selected via Annoncement from  of collection of Notification inside Where() method 
  in this case you have to use SelectMany

And in any case may use join for this

```
var users=(from u in db.Users
         join s in db.Suppliers
         on u.OrganisationId equals s.OrganisationId
         join rs in db.RequestSuppliers
         on s.Id equals rs.SupplierId
         join a in db.Announcements
         on rs.AnnouncementId equals a.Id
         join n in db.Notifications
         on a.Id equals n.AnnouncementId
         select u);
```

Comment: Both solutions worked. Thanks! I had to add the where clauses in both queries for the notificationId, but otherwise both worked like a charm.